# Ionic2-Super-Tabs content become empty when change tabs

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic-tabs

I am using ionic2-super-tabs v4.3.1. I have 3 tabs which is used inside a component (It is not for main navigation. Using as a segmented control). I have set a component as the Root.

For the first time page load, tab 0 is selected by default. Content of this tab is visible. When selecting the 2nd tab, the contents become empty. Also, when selecting the 1st tab again, it's content also become empty.

Issue is started to happen suddenly only on iOS v14.5 upwards. All other iOS versions and Android no issue.

Anyone else facing similar kind of issue? Please share with me if anyone manage to fix this issue

```html
<ion-content class="bodyContent">
    <div style="height: 100%" *ngIf="isShowTab">
        <super-tabs [scrollTabs]="false" id="timeline" #timeline (tabSelect)="onTabSelect($event)">
            <super-tab [root]="Page1" [rootParams]="page3Parameter" title="One"></super-tab>
            <super-tab [root]="Page2" [rootParams]="page2Parameter" title="Two"></super-tab>
            <super-tab [root]="Page3" [rootParams]="page1Parameter" title="Three"></super-tab>
        </super-tabs>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Child page module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ChartPage2 } from './chart2';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ChartPage2,
  ],
  providers: [],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(ChartPage2),
  ],
})
export class ChartPageModule {}
```

Child page

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPage} from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-chart2',
  templateUrl: 'chart2.html',
})
export class ChartPage2 {

  constructor(){
    console.log('RootPage init');
  }

  public onEnter(): void {
    console.info('Workaround: Tab1Component -> onEnter. Loaded state:');
    this.initView();
  }

  private initView(): void {
    console.log("Root page InitView")
  }
}
```

Child page html

```
<ion-content>
  <div class="taptoretry">
    <div style="font-weight: bold; color:black; font-size:110%; display: inline;color :rgb(70, 69, 69);">There is content in the root component.
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Can you share `Page1` code.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Thanks for the comment. I have added child page codes.

Comment: Are you open to changing the whole process, I can show you a better simpler way to achieve the same result.

Comment: Yes, it will be really helpful. I had try multiple workarounds with ionic2-supertabs. But doesn't seems to be working